# Gatsby/Wordpress: GraphQLError: Fragment cannot be spread here as objects of type "foo" can never be of type "bar"

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I am using GraphQL to pull information from custom ACF fields in Wordpress onto my Gatsby site. My query originally queried three ACF fields (ImageRow, TextRow and ImageTextRow), however I then deleted the first two rows and removed them from the query. I then. added a new row called HeroRow, however since then I have been getting this error:

```
ERROR #85901  GRAPHQL

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Fragment cannot be spread here as objects of type "WPGraphQL_Page_Customcontentblocks" can never be of
type "WPGraphQL_Page_Customcontentblocks_Customcontentblocks_HeroRow".

File: gatsby-node.js:82:28
```

My query is as follows:

```
    query {
        wpgraphql {
            pages(first: 5000, where: {status : PUBLISH}){
                nodes {
                    title
                    uri
                    status
                    content
                    customContentBlocks {
                      customcontentblocks {
                        ... on WPGraphQL_Page_Customcontentblocks_Customcontentblocks_ImageTextRow {
                            fieldGroupName
                            version
                            imageV1 {
                                sourceUrl
                            }
                            titleV1
                            subtitleV1
                            textV1
                            linksV1 {
                                links {
                                  target
                                  title
                                  url
                                }
                              }
                            imageV2 {
                                sourceUrl
                            }
                            titleV2
                            subtitleV2
                            textV2
                            listV2 {
                                listItem
                            }
                            ctaV2 {
                                target
                                title
                                url
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        ... on WPGraphQL_Page_Customcontentblocks_Customcontentblocks_HeroRow {
                            fieldGroupName
                            title
                            image {
                              sourceUrl
                            }
                            links {
                              link {
                                target
                                title
                                url
                              }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am able to query the `ImageTextRow` without issue if I query it alone, but whenever the HeroRow is included I get the same error message.

I have set up my HeroRow layout in the same way as my ImageTextRow layout (both are siblings and sit under the `customContentBlocks` field group), so I would expect the query to work the same for both.

I have also tested the query on the Wordpress end using the `GraphiQL IDE` and the query works fine on the Wordpress end, the problem just seems to be on the Gatsby end.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this issue, however I'm not entirely sure why this fixed it:

By chaging the order of the different layouts in my query so that the offending layout (`HeroRow`) was NOT the last one in the query, everything worked fine:

```
    query {
        wpgraphql {
            pages(first: 5000, where: {status : PUBLISH}){
                nodes {
                    title
                    uri
                    status
                    content
                    customContentBlocks {
                      customcontentblocks {
                        ... on WPGraphQL_Page_Customcontentblocks_Customcontentblocks_HeroRow {
                            fieldGroupName
                            title
                            image {
                              sourceUrl
                            }
                            links {
                              link {
                                target
                                title
                                url
                              }
                            }
                        }                        
                        ... on WPGraphQL_Page_Customcontentblocks_Customcontentblocks_ImageTextRow {
                            fieldGroupName
                            version
                            imageV1 {
                                sourceUrl
                            }
                            titleV1
                            subtitleV1
                            textV1
                            linksV1 {
                                links {
                                  target
                                  title
                                  url
                                }
                              }
                            imageV2 {
                                sourceUrl
                            }
                            titleV2
                            subtitleV2
                            textV2
                            listV2 {
                                listItem
                            }
                            ctaV2 {
                                target
                                title
                                url
                            }
                          }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have since added multiple subsequent rows and all is working as expected.